# Maintaining Private State

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, access-modifiers, private-members

I was reading about private state maintenance in javascript across files having same module.

Say we have file1:

```
var Module = (function(){
    //Some private variables declared.
    // and initialized.

})();
```

and we have file2:

```
var Module = (function(myModule){
    //Here the same private variables are required.
    // And the following implementation enables it.
    var _private = myModule._private = myModule._private || {},
    _seal = myModule._seal = myModule._seal || function () {
        delete myModule._private;
        delete myModule._seal;
        delete myModule._unseal;
    },
    _unseal = myModule._unseal = myModule._unseal || function () {
        myModule._private = _private;
        myModule._seal = _seal;
        myModule._unseal = _unseal;
     };    

   return myModule;
}(Module || {}));
```

The part I was not able to understand was `var _private = myModule._private = myModule._private || {},`

I thought `var _private = myModule._private || {}` would do the same thing. Why is it done the way mentioned above? And moreover wouldn't `deleting myModule._private, myModule._seal and myModule._unseal` make it inaccessible for any further use? But the article says it seals and unseals the private variables for use in other files there by maintaining the private state of the module. Any hints or insights regarding this pattern?

The article that I was referring to is [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)

Comment: Your second snippet doesn't return anything. I'm not sure why you are overwriting `Module` with `undefined`.

Comment: @pimvdb: Its my mistake. I do return myModule

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, `myModule._private` can be undefined. If so, `var _private = myModule._private || {}` will always set _private to {} and leave myModule._private undefined (what leads to delete undefined), while the longer code will set myModule._private to {} if it was undefined and leave it untouched in other case, and then do _private = myModule._private;

So all this spaghetti is done just to do safe `delete myModule._private`.

Comment: but myModule is an object passed on to this file. Is it even right in terms of design to change myModule._private variable that comes as input?

Comment: I think the goal is to implement something like partial classes in c#. In this case, you want to treat input and returned value as object of the same class - so you should have possibility to access and change "private" vars which comes from other file (but same module).